# What language or file type do you use HTTP methods with?

Tags: asp.net, rest, http

I want to use HTTP methods (GET/PUT/POST/DELETE) with an Azure resource and even have the URIs to do so. I understand that this practice utilizes RESTful web services.

What file type or programming language do I use to call these? On every documentation site that I have found, the only thing I see is something like the following, without any context:

`Method   Request URI
POST     https://media.windows.net/api/Channels(‘*channelid*’)/Stop`

So, where do I include this? HTML? C#? Do I create an ASP.NET web app and place it somewhere in there?

This would be very helpful to know so that I can utilize these methods!

Answer (score 1):

You can use any programming language that has http support, or indeed your browser (most have native support to alter requests).
A more convenient alternative to test the api might be a rest client, a popular one being [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), a browser plugin.

Comment: Thanks, @jojomojo. If I want to make a webpage with 2 components -- a drop-down list and a button, where the button makes a call using the selected drop-down list value -- and use HTTP methods, would I just create an ASP.NET web application and include the HTTP calls upon button press?